# hibernate OneToMay-ManyToOne пустая коллекция

Tags: spring, hibernate

Здравствуйте.
разбираюсь с Hibernate и не могу понять ...почему возвращается пустая коллекция при вызове геттера.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bid") 
public class Bid {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bid_id",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = 
FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Order> getOrders() {
return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
this.orders = orders;
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "orders")
 public class Order {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private long id;
 @Column(name = "title")
 private String title;

 @ManyToOne(optional = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = 
 CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "bid")
 private Bid bid_id;
```

Comment: Ну Вы хоть напишите как Вы вызываете геттер

Comment: Set orderSet = bid.getOrders();  Мне понятно как получить результат используя запрос на уровне DAO. Но насколько я понимаю гибернейт сам должен заполнить коллекцию исходя из связи? Или я не прав? Или нужно использовать запрос...

Comment: Когда Вы получали свой объект bid, то выполняли какую-то функцию или запускали Query. Если это делали из Eclipse, то в console вывелся SQL запрос в БД. Попробуйте запустить этот запрос в БД. Он вернет записи из orders?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Думаю Ваш ответ поможет разобраться...пойду документацию читать)